# Group law of elliptic curves on finite fields

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves, group-isomorphism, bilinear-form

If the underlying field is $\mathbb{C}$, there is a bijective map between a given elliptic curve and $\mathbb{C} \mathbin{/} \Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is a lattice uniquely determined by the elliptic curve. This map is a holomorphic isomorphism and a group isomorphism as well, and is as such unique. In $\mathbb{C} \mathbin{/} \Lambda$, the group law is merely the addition.

I think that the above is correct, but please let me know if some finesse escapes me (regarding the uniqueness of the map and of the lattice, for instance).

The proper question question is: Is there a similar parameterization for the case that the underlying field is a finite field (some analogon to Weierstrass's $\wp$-function)? That is, does a parameterization space exist, in which the group law is an addition (or some kind of elementary operation)? Or does otherwise the group law just happen to work in analogy to the complex case, but does not have deeper connections, as in the complex case?

The same question holds also for bilinear pairings (in particular for the Weil-pairing).

Comment: The unifying theme is to consider elliptic curves as schemes. This you can do over any field (indeed, over any other scheme $S$, as long as there is a morphism $E \to S$). The true reason why $E$ has a group structure is because the connected component of the identity the Picard group of $E$ does. By considering various special cases, one recovers the classical definitions. For example, setting $S = \operatorname{spec} \mathbf{C}$ (and passing through some isomorphisms) gives the elliptic curve as a complex torus. You might also be interested in looking up moduli spaces of elliptic curves.

Comment: @LetGBeTheGraph IMO to answer OP it is very overkill to refer to shemes when one only needs to think about classical varieties over $k$. Moreover to describe the group law one may just use chord-and-tangent so you don't *need* the picard group, I think this obfuscates the basic ideas.

Comment: @LetGBeTheGraph. Thank you, but I am not too familiar with those advanced concepts. What should $S$ be for a finite field instead of $\mathbb{C}$? Yielding what instead of a complex torus?

Comment: The group law can be defined by the [chord and tangent process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#The_group_law) which is purely algebraic so the group law doesn't really work by analogy, more by definition. If you are looking for some parametrisation as a lattice, you'll miss out in the case $\mathbb{F}_p$ - there is no nice topology for your $\wp$ to converge in. However there is an analogy to be had in the $\mathbb{Q}_p$ case, the convergence doesn't always happen but you do get the so-called *Tate Curves* when it works out. See Silverman's Advanced Topics book.

Comment: @Mummytheturkey Thank you for the hints. I guessed that there is no parameterization, at least not between a $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space and the elliptic curve, for cardinality reasons. But now I know where to look at if I want to study this topic more deeply.

Comment: @Loic My mistake. As Mummy the turkey writes, you only need the classical group law when working over fields. But with regards to the "parametrisation space" you ask for, I suppose the most general one is the Picard group (but the group law there is certainly not elementary). There is also a purpose in defining elliptic curves over other rings, such as $\mathbf{Z}$ or $\mathbf{Z}[1/n]$, where the classical group law does not work.